# How to save the firebase user data into the Redux store? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm trying to do that when I login with firebase i´ll save the data of the user into the redux store. I tried to do it using onAuthStateChanged but I not know how to save the data into the redux store.

This is my onAuthStateChanged of firebase

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: "USER_LOGIN",
      payload: { user: user.providerData[0] }
    });
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGOUT" });
  }
});
```

I'm sending the data with payload: { user: user.providerData[0] } but really I don't know how to change the state with the info. See my redux store

```
const initialState = {
  logged: null,
  user: {}
};
```

An idea of how can i change the state? (When i console.log( user.providerData[0]) inside my onAuthStateChanged I receive email, displayName, photoURL and other things.

Comment: Could you extend your question with the reducers?

Comment: Sorry, I´ve fixed it, thanks!